# Extract security group id from security group name in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to write a generic script in terraform to create ALB (in AWS).
The security groups are created (sg_alb) but not in the same script. It is pre-created
I want to extract the id of the security group and pass it
security_groups    = ["${aws_security_group.lb_sg.id}"]

I have seen examples where the above reference is made but that is assuming the security group is created along with ALB

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you
Kumar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is what Terraform [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/security_group.html) are for. If your Terraform module is getting a security group name as a variable, then you would look up the security group like this:

```
data "aws_security_group" "lb_sg" {
  name = var.security_group_name
}
```

Then you could use the data source when creating your ALB, like this:

```
security_groups = [data.aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]
```

Comment: I only see `name` declared in the `lb_sg` data source, but you reference `lb_sg.id`. Can you clarify?

Comment: @RodrigoM the way a data source works is Terraform looks up the data source via the AWS API, based on the parameters you provide. Then all the attributes of the data source are available for you to reference later. Per the documentation here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/security_group.html you can lookup a security group by `name`, `id`, `tags`, `filter` or `vpc_id`. Once you have done that the values `id`, `name`, `tags`, `vpc_id` and `description` are available for reference.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I guess the logical place to define this would be in vars.tf
 data "aws_security_group" "lb_sg" {
  name = var.security_group_name
}

Comment: It really doesn't matter to Terraform where you define it, but I would only define the var in `vars.tf`. I would define the data source in the same file as your load balancer resource. That would follow the general practice I have seen in Terraform documentation and examples.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the clarification. One more small clarification. I made that change and ran terraform plan and I see like this
+ security_groups            = [
          + "sg-00ee975248d230286",
        ]
Does the , mean it expects multiple values for the security groups . I only want to attach one security group

Comment: It accepts multiple values, but there is only one being assigned, which is fine.